# PHP throwing XDebug errors ONLY in command line mode

Tags: php

I've been having a few problems running PHP-based utilities within the command line ever since I enabled the XDebug. It runs just fine when executing script through a browser, but once I try an execute a script on the command line, it throws the following errors:

```
h:\www\test>@php test.php
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'E:\development\xampplite\php\ext\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension in Unknown on line 0

h:\www\test>
```

The script runs just fine after this, but it's something I can't seem to wrap my head around. Could it be a path issue within my php.ini config?  I'm not sure if that's the case considering it throws the same error no matter where I access the `@php` environmental variable.

Also, all paths within my php.ini are absolute. Not really sure what's going on here.

Comment: This sounds like a case of multiple php.ini's, and the CLI interface using a different one. Can you do a `phpinfo()` to see which file gets used?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Chances are you are using two different `.ini` files :

- One for used by Apache
- And another for CLI

Or maybe you have the same problem with PHP used by Apache, but don't see that warning, as it's in Apache's error log -- and it's only a warning.

The solution, basically, is to load the Xdebug extension using :

```
zend_extension=/.../xdebug.so
```

instead of :

```
extension=/.../xdebug.so
```

This is exactly what the error message indicates : `Xdebug MUST be loaded as a Zend extension` *-- except it doesn't tell you how to do that.*

Note :

- I'm using an absolute path to `xdebug.so` -- you're already doing that, which is nice *(it's required anyway)*
- But I am also using **`zend_extension`** : Xdebug is an extension that hooks deep into PHP's Zend engine, which means using `extension` is not enough.

For more informations, and as a reference, see the [Installation / activation](http://xdebug.org/docs/install) page in Xdebug's documentation.

Comment: Also note per above and per the install docs that you should use 'zend_extension' not 'zend_extension_ts' for the latest versions of PHP.  I've seen zend_extension_ts recommended in quite a few places.  Reference: http://xdebug.org/docs/install

Comment: A footnote for Windows users: the path to xdebug needs to be a full path in quotes (eg. `zend_extension="C:\Program Files\ ... "`)